# Accessing and writing 3D array in Java, Android

Tags: java, android

My program needs to work with 3 dimensional arrays. It has a menu where I can choose between the top level of the array and the next two levels are loaded in based on what the user chooses. All levels must be editable too.

The structure:
Top-level: Array[this][][]
This is where the user chooses an element of the array. In this case I am working on a workout app and the user chooses which workout he/she wants to do.

Second-level: Array[][this][]
There are always 4 elements to this level. The workout name, the duration or count of the exercise types, the set values (100 pushups in 40-30-30 sets) and the resting time between sets.

Third-level: Array[][][this]
The values.

What would the best way be to go about doing this?

Comment: Are you sure a 3D array is appropriate?  How can you mix ints and Strings?

Comment: I am certain I need some kind of a data structure that has 3 levels that I can access. If there is a better solution than a 3D array I'm open to hear that:)

Comment: A tree-like, maybe. or actual objects model with parent-child relations.

Comment: A `Map` data structure is much better suited than a 3D array. Something like this `Map<String, Workout>` sounds more appropriate to me. The `String` in the first level of the map would be the name of the workout. The `Workout` object itself could be an object could contain `Exercise` objects that contain the exercise names and values.

Comment: @NathanNorman Could you please explain me how this works? I've never used Maps

Comment: @BenceMátrai There is a multitude of high quality resource on this basic Java concept on the internet. Here is the official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: The first challenge here is not with Maps or arrays.  It is with properly modelling the data.  You need to create classes which represent the concepts presented.  Start by creating a Workout class.  It will have a String name.  Then create an Exercise class.  A workout will have a List<Exercise>.  An Exercise will have a name (i.e. pushups), and a List<Integer> of intervals (i.e. 40, 30, 30).  The rest time (an int) will go into the Workout class.  Etc..  Once you model the data, it is easier to reason about how to store it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll try these ideas!